# Drag & Drop change style after drop into specific div

Tags: jquery, css, drag-and-drop

I have found nice script in: http://jsfiddle.net/wfG3L/554/ , it is about Drag & Drop.

I would like to change width or height of class .card if I drop it into .stackDrop1 or .stackDrop2 and give it back after droping into #launchPad.

Can anyone help me? I would really appreciate it.

```
$("#launchPad").height($(window).height() - 20);
var dropSpace = $(window).width() - $("#launchPad").width();
$("#dropZone").width(dropSpace - 10);
$("#dropZone").height($("#launchPad").height());

$(".card").draggable({
    appendTo: "body",
    cursor: "move",
    helper: 'clone',
    revert: "invalid",
});

$("#launchPad").droppable({
    tolerance: "intersect",
    accept: ".card",
    activeClass: "ui-state-default",
    hoverClass: "ui-state-hover",
    drop: function(event, ui) {
        $("#launchPad").append($(ui.draggable));
    }
});

$(".stackDrop1").droppable({
    tolerance: "intersect",
    accept: ".card",
    activeClass: "ui-state-default",
    hoverClass: "ui-state-hover",
    drop: function(event, ui) {        
        $(this).append($(ui.draggable));

    }
});

$(".stackDrop2").droppable({
    tolerance: "intersect",
    accept: ".card",
    activeClass: "ui-state-default",
    hoverClass: "ui-state-hover",
    drop: function(event, ui) {        
        $(this).append($(ui.draggable));
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this css:

```
.stack .card.ui-draggable
{
    background-color:orange;
}
```